# Getting average cost?

Tags: statistics

I posted a question previously and I got crucified for not having enough info.

So let me put it this way, maybe someone can explain why it's so difficult to make the transition.

I'll be calculating how much a pound of cat food will cost. So I have two brands I buy: `BrandA` & `BrandB`; each is `30 pounds`. The formula is `(BrandA + BrandB)/60`

So, today, the price of BrandA for today was `$20`, and for BrandB was `$40`. This means that today, the pound of cat food averaged $1 a pound: (20+40)/60

Now let's say I want to get the average cost of a pound of cat food for a 3-day period.

So, on Monday, BrandA is `$20` & BrandB is `$40`. Tuesday: BrandA is `$30` & BrandB is `$50`. Wednesday: BrandA is `$10` & BrandB is `$60`.

How would you get the average cost of 1-pound of cat food in this 3-day period?

Comment: In your first example, what does $20 refer to? $20 per pound or per 30 pounds? You may describe it more clearly.

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting? I have to say, just because you don't understand or don't know, doesn't mean that you have to downvote.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, the cost is a $1 per pound.

Comment: So you may edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: And negative scoring can be reversed for a better explained question.

Comment: What else can I explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monday:

$$\frac{20+40}{60}=1 \qquad (\text{units = \$/lb})$$

Tuesday
$$\frac{30+50}{60}=\frac{4}{3}$$

Wednesday
$$\frac{10+60}{60}=\frac{7}{6}$$

Average for three days:
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{7}{6} \right)=\frac{1}{3} \times\frac{21}{6}=\$1.17 \text{\lb} \qquad \text{(nearest cent})$$

This is working to the assumption that the mass of cat food purchased each day remains constant.